# Why is the Ansible task failing without giving any error?

Tags: ansible, centos, rpm, ansible-2.x, rhel

I have an Ansible task running on RHEL and CentOS machines.

```yaml
- name: Git version (Fedora)
  command: rpm -qi git
  args:
    warn: no
  register: fedora_git
  tags:
    - git
```

But this task is getting failed without any error.

```json
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["rpm", "-qi", "git"], "delta": "0:00:00.066596", "end": "2023-05-23 01:28:16.302918", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-05-23 01:28:16.236322", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "package git is not installed", "stdout_lines": ["package git is not installed"]}
```

Tried with `shell` module, but getting the same error.

Comment: In the error it is saying "package git is not installed", did you check this?

Comment: That's the std output of the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ansible it is generally recommended to use tasks specific modules instead of `command` or `shell` if available and possible. In your case the [`package_facts` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html) in order to get package information as facts.

A minimal [Example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html#examples) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather the package facts
    ansible.builtin.package_facts:
      manager: auto

  - name: Show Facts
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"

  - name: Print the package names only
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | dict2items | map(attribute='key') }}"
```

will result into a list output of the installed packages, or a task like

```yaml
  - name: Show Git Facts
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages.git }}"
    when: ansible_facts.packages.git is defined # means installed
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Git Facts] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: git
    release: 24.el7_9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.8.3.1
```

For other format and information you need to make further adjustments.

---

> *But this task is getting `FAILED` without any error. ... Tried with `shell` module, but getting the same error.*

Right, this is the expected behavior and result for querying the local package database for information of not installed packages and [caused by Return Code (RC)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254747/266568).

Whereby a command like

```bash
rpm -qi git; echo $?
Name        : git
Version     : 1.8.3.1
Release     : 24.el7_9
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Fri 14 Apr 2023 11:04:29 AM CEST
Group       : Development/Tools
Size        : 23265551
License     : GPLv2
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Wed 22 Feb 2023 09:30:47 AM CET, Key ID 199e2f91fd431d51
Source RPM  : git-1.8.3.1-24.el7_9.src.rpm
Build Date  : Tue 21 Feb 2023 05:26:24 PM CET
Build Host  : x86-vm-37.build.eng.bos.redhat.com
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla>
Vendor      : Red Hat, Inc.
URL         : http://git-scm.com/
Summary     : Fast Version Control System
Description :
Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
and full access to internals.

The git rpm installs the core tools with minimal dependencies.  To
install all git packages, including tools for integrating with other
SCMs, install the git-all meta-package.
0
```

will provide package information and a `"rc": 0`, a command like

```bash
rpm -qi not-installed; echo $?
package not-installed is not installed
1
```

will not and provide a `"rc": 1`.

**Further Reading**

- [Return Values - Common `rc`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#rc)
- [What does `echo $?` do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501129/266568)
- The behavior can be adjusted by [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure)

  > *... based on the return code.*